# Instanciando objeto em um construtor

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde.

Eu gostaria de saber se e possivel instanciar um objeto no construtor javascript.

```
constructor{
  this.objDificultControll = new dificultControll();
}
```

pois tenho o seguinte erro

> dificultControll is not defined

Comment: O que é dificultControll? Onde ele está definido?

Comment: Está faltando os parênteses em `constructor() { ... }`, e, como a mensagem diz, `dificultControll` não foi definido no escopo. Verifique se criou com o nome certo no local certo

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal =)!